# Adding non-duplicate strings from one txt to another in Python3.3

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I have 2 text files (`new.txt` and `master.txt`). Each has different data stored as such:

```
Cory 12 12:40:12.016221
Suzy 64 12:40:33.404614
Trent 145 12:40:56.640052
```

(catagorised by the first set of numbers appearing on each line)

I have to scan each line of `new.txt` for the name (e.g. Suzy), check if there is a duplicate in `master.txt` and if there **isn't**, then I add that line to `master.txt` catagorized by that line's number (e.g. **64** in `Suzy 64 12:40:33.404614`).

I have written the following script, but it falls into a loop of checking the 1st line of `new.txt` (I know why, I just don't know how to work around not closing `fileinput.input(new.txt)` so that I can then open `fileinput.input(master.txt)` further down the loop). I feel like I've highly over complicated things for myself and any help is appreciated.

```
import fileinput
import re

end_of_file = False

while end_of_file == False:
    for line in fileinput.input('new.txt', inplace=1):
        end_of_file = fileinput.isstdin() #ends while loop if on last line of new.txt
        user_f_line_list = line.split()
        master_f = open('master.txt', 'r')
        master_f_read = master_f.read()
        master_f.close()
        fileinput.close()
        if not re.findall(user_f_line_list[0], master_f_read):
            for line in fileinput.input('master.txt', inplace=1):
                master_line_list = line.split()
                if int(user_f_line_list[1]) <= int(master_line_list[1]):
                    written = False
                    while written == False:
                        written = True
                        print(' '.join(user_f_line_list))
                print(line, end='')
            fileinput.close()
```

And for reference, `master.txt` starts with `startline 0` and ends with `endline 1000000000000000` so that it is impossible for the categorizing to be out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Open `master.txt` into a list with `readlines()`.
2. Use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the `collections` module - it is the same as a regular dict but preserves the order. Make each key the unique element - a tuple in this case (e.g. `("Cory", 12)`). Make the value whatever comes after.
3. Now you can very rapidly check to see if the entry is present by `if key in my_dict:`.
4. If it isn't, you can insert it. If you need to insert in order, it'll take a bit more work, but not too much. I would insert in the end, convert to a list when all is done, and apply a `sort` function to the list with a custom function to specify how to sort.
5. Output it back to the file.

I won't say it's necessarily shorter than your solution, but it is a lot cleaner.

Comment: This is great. I'll work on it and post an update with the new script.